# VS2017 Issue with typescript compiler options path not being supported by MS build

Tags: typescript, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, compiler-options

I already found that MSBuild for VS2017 does not currently support paths in the tsconfig.json according to the docs. But, I was hoping someone might have a workaround for it.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@example/utils/*": ["app/utils/*"],
      "@example/pipes/*": ["app/pipes/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> VS2017 Issue with typescript compiler options path not being supported by MS build

If you want specify the compiler options paths by MSBuild properties, I am afraid you can not do that.

As we know, compiler options can be specified using MSBuild properties within an MSBuild project, but some options are **only allowed** in `tsconfig.json`, and not through command-line switches and compiler option **paths** is also not supported by in MSBuild:

[image]

So it seems we could not specify the compiler options paths by MSBuild at this moment.